# Getting error while executing dao

Tags: java, sql, oracle, prepared-statement, ora-00917

Hello friends i am running code given below which contains the setLogTimeEntery function and when this function is executed i am getting

"Error : java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00917: missing comma"

error and my database is oracle plese any one tell me wht is the problem.

```
public int setLogTimeEntery(Connection con, LogTimeBean ltb) {

int ans = 0;

    try{
        psmt=con.prepareStatement("Insert into TR_LogTime values((Select count(*) from Tr_LogTime) + 1 ,(select sysdate from dual) , Prj_Id=?,Area_Id=?,Actvity_Id=?,ID_No=?,Work_Date=(select to_date(?,'dd/mm/yyyy')from dual) ,Work_Hours=?,Division=?,Description=?,Remarks=?,Work_Week=?)");
        psmt.clearParameters();
        psmt.setString(1,ltb.getLt_Prj_Id());
        psmt.setInt(2,ltb.getLt_Area_Id());
        psmt.setInt(3,ltb.getLt_Actvity_Id());
        psmt.setInt(4, ltb.getLt_ID_No());
        psmt.setString(5, ltb.getLt_Work_Date());
        psmt.setFloat(6,ltb.getLt_Work_Hours());
        psmt.setInt(7,ltb.getLt_Division());
        psmt.setString(8, ltb.getLt_Description());
        psmt.setString(9, ltb.getLt_Remarks());
        psmt.setInt(10, ltb.getLt_Work_Week());
        ans=psmt.executeUpdate();
        psmt.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error : "+e);
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your Oracle SQL statement (as defined in the prepared statement) is valid.  When using the `insert into [table] values(...)` syntax, you don't use `column=value` expressions.

If you're specifying all of the column values in the correct order, then use this:

```
psmt=con.prepareStatement("Insert into TR_LogTime values((Select count(*) from Tr_LogTime) + 1 ,(select sysdate from dual), ?, ?, ?, ?,(select to_date(?,'dd/mm/yyyy')from dual) ,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Otherwise, if you're only specifying a subset of the columns, use the syntax of

```
insert into TR_LogTime (col1, col2, col3, ...) values (?, ?, ?, ...)
```

(I didn't specify the exact column names in your example since I don't know all of them)

[More on this syntax](http://www.remote-dba.cc/t_garmany_easysql_INSERT.htm).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Insert into TR_LogTime (XXX, YYY, Prj_Id, Area_id, Activity_Id, ID_No, Work_Date, Work_Hours, Division, Description, Remarks, Work_Week) values (
(Select count(*) from Tr_LogTime) + 1 , (select sysdate from dual) , ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

You'll need to replace XXX and YYY with the appropriate column names